# Is there a way to find the minimum/maximum value of a specific column in a set range within that column?

Tags: python

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1KKr.png)

Assuming that there are 3 columns,
 the first column has an ID that goes from 1-40 and repeats after reaching 40, going back to 1 and starts increasing again.

the second column has an ID that goes from 1-18000, but increments after every 40 rows, which makes the data table extremely large with a size of 600k+ values to store.

the third column has random values.

How can I find the minimum value of the third column in the range of 1-40 in the first column for ID 1,2,3,4, ....... and so on in the second column?
As the data to work with is quite large, what would be the best way to run this type of search?

I have added an image to show how the table looks like:

Comment: How do you store the "table"?

Comment: i store it in a matrix